# Android Kitkat gallery having permission issue with camera

Tags: android, android-camera, adb, android-gallery

I am using following adb command to open camera app in video recording mode directly:

```
adb shell am start -a android.media.action.VIDEO_CAPTURE -n  com.android.gallery3d/com.android.camera.CameraActivity
```

It has been all working fine until lately the comand started failing on KitKat:

```
C:\Users\asiaynrf>adb shell am start -a android.media.action.VIDEO_CAPTURE -n  com.android.gallery3d/com.android.camera.CameraActivity
Starting: Intent { act=android.media.action.VIDEO_CAPTURE cmp=com.android.gallery3d/com.android.camera.CameraActivity }
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.media.action.VIDEO_CAPTURE flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.gallery3d/com.android.
camera.CameraActivity } from null (pid=2485, uid=2000) not exported from uid 10038
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1465)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1419)
        at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerNative.java:2141)
        at com.android.commands.am.Am.runStart(Am.java:680)
        at com.android.commands.am.Am.onRun(Am.java:270)
        at com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:47)
        at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:76)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:243)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have no idea why it started failing and why Gallery 3D does not have permissions to this app. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That activity is not exported and is no longer accessible from outside of the app itself. Only the app can start up that activity.

Comment: What should be my command now? I though Gallery3d is the one which governs the camera app

Comment: @Californicated: "What should be my command now?" -- I am not aware that there is a command that you can use, though I have never researched this point. "I though Gallery3d is the one which governs the camera app" -- on Android 4.4 hardware, like the Nexus 4, the camera app is not the gallery app.

Comment: @CommonsWare, Only the app and root can start up that activity. Californicated is trying to run it with `shell` account - "from null (pid=2485, uid=2000)"

Comment: Is it official from google that they are not going to allow this command? This is very well supported from in JB?